# Dynamic dependant data validation in multiple cells

Tags: excel, validation

I am banging my head with the following issue - I have a table where I input all invoices received with customer name, invoice number and amount. In a separate sheet I have a table where I enter all payments on invoices received.
In the Payments table I have created a data validation list for the Customer input column and I want to have another data validation for the invoice number based on the selected customer.
In other words I want to limit the invoice column to only include invoices from the selected customer.

I have attached a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zs5T.png) to demonstrate what I am trying to do.

Thank you for your support.

Comment: What have you tried and what, exactly, is the problem?

Comment: As I wrote above "I want to have another data validation for the invoice number based on the selected customer" which to be valid for all records in a table column (see the screenshot attached). I know that the filter function does not work in Data validation list. I have also tried with offset function but the problem is that my data is not sorted. I have also searched even on Page 3 in Google results for Data validation and filter and anything related but with no luck.